# Como montar SELECT?

Tags: sql, select

Tenho uma tabela de Produtos com:

```
ProCodigo - Primary Key de Produto
ProNome
```

E outra tabela de Histórico de Preços com:

```
HisCodigo - Primary Key de Histórico
HisData
HisPreco
ProCodigo - Foreign Key de Produto
```

Preciso montar um SELECT que traga os produtos com o preço atual, ou seja o preço mais recente da tabela de Histórico, porém até agora não consegui fazer.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você quer montar o SQL via C# (linq) ou via código sql para executar no banco?

Comment: Código SQL para executar no banco

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT P.PROCODIGO, P.PRONOME, H.HISPRECO
FROM PRODUTO P
INNER JOIN HISTORICO H ON P.PROCODIGO = H.PROCODIGO
WHERE H.HISDATA = (SELECT MAX(HISDATA) FROM HISTORICO WHERE PROCODIGO = P.PROCODIGO)
```

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado, resolveu meu problema!

Answer (score 4):

Segue uma alternativa a consulta proposta pelo Cigano.

A consulta abaixo não vai funcionar no `MySQL`, mas é valida no `PostgreSQL`, `Oracle` e `SQL Server`.

```
WITH CTE_PRODUTO AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.PROCODIGO ORDER BY H.HISDATA DESC) INDICE,
        P.PROCODIGO, 
        P.PRONOME, 
        H.HISPRECO
    FROM PRODUTO P
    INNER JOIN HISTORICO H ON P.PROCODIGO = H.PROCODIGO
)

SELECT PROCODIGO, PRONOME, HISPRECO 
FROM CTE_PRODUTO 
WHERE INDICE = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```
        SELECT
        PRONOME
        FROM
        PRODUTOS P
        INNER JOIN
        HISTORICO H
        ON (P.PROCODIGO = H.PROCODIGO)
        WHERE
        H.HISDATA = (
            SELECT
            MAX (HISDATA)
            FROM
            HISTORICO H2
            ON
            H.PROCODIGO = H2.PROCODIGO

        )
```