# Como montar SELECT em lambda C#?

Tags: c#, sql, select, entity-framework-6, expressões-lambda

Recentemente pedi ajuda para montar um SELECT para trazer o preço dos produtos

[Como montar SELECT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109744/como-montar-select)

Me deram essa solução que funcionou perfeitamente:

```
SELECT P.PROCODIGO, P.PRONOME, H.HISPRECO
FROM PRODUTO P
INNER JOIN HISTORICO H ON P.PROCODIGO = H.PROCODIGO
WHERE H.HISDATA = (SELECT MAX(HISDATA) FROM HISTORICO WHERE PROCODIGO = P.PROCODIGO)
```

Porém agora preciso montar esse mesmo SELECT em lambda com C#, pois comecei a usar Entity. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Obrigado!

Comment: você esta usando contexto?

Comment: Uso, mas também uso unidade de trabalho e repositórios.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ficaria assim:

```
var produtos = db.Historicos
                 .Include(h => h.Produto)
                 .OrderByDescending(h => h.HistoricoData)
                 .GroupBy(h => h.ProdutoId)
                 .Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault())
                 .ToList();
```

No Entity Framework não se deve pensar como no SQL. A maneira de fazer as coisas é diferente. O SQL gerado possivelmente não será igual, mas o resultado será.

Comment: Entendi, mas no caso eu estou usando repositório da unidade de trabalho, faz diferença?

Comment: Faz: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80696/2999

Comment: Eu estou tentando criar um método no meu repo, mas o Include pede uma string path. No caso o Históricos deve ser um DbSet<Historico>?

Comment: Pode ser um string ou uma expression. Não use repositório sobre EF. Você leu o link que eu te mandei?

Comment: Sim, mas o meu projeto já está montado com repos e unidade de trabalho então por enquanto não vou mudar. Mas no meu include não aceita expression, o db no caso é um DbContext?

Comment: Bom, você irá trabalhar com limitações e seu projeto terá problemas em breve por sua decisão. Aceitaria o `Include` se você tivesse feito do jeito certo. O db é sim um `DbContext`.

Comment: Eu vou mudar meu projeto, só preciso ler melhor o que você me passou e estudar um pouco mais. Mas eu tive que fazer com linq o Select, mesmo assim muito obrigado pela ajuda!